# Nesting in css3

Tags: css, sencha-touch-2

I am very new to css and Sencha Touch 2. While working on some tutorial on Sencha Touch 2,I see a CSS file having code like

```
/* Increase height of list item so title and narrative fit */
.x-list .x-list-item {
     min-height: 10.5em!important;
     height:7.5em;
}
/* Move the disclosure button up to account for the list item height increase */
.x-list .x-list-disclosure {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 4.0em;
     right: 0.10em;
}
```

Is  `.x-list .x-list-item`   a css nesting concept and `x-list`  a class name?
Also , is this concept purely a CSS concept or Sencha Touch concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a pure CSS concept, so this syntax means

```
.x-list .x-list-item
```

Select an element with class `x-list-item` which is nested under element having class `x-list`

The same goes for second syntax.

If you want to make it more stricter, you can use `element.class` selector so it will select only if it matches `element.class` combination, so if taken your example..

Using something like

```
div.x-list span.x-list-item {
   /* This will select span only which is having a class 
      x-list-item which is nested under div element having class 
      x-list */
}
```

Comment: Could u please suggest some tutorials for this. Currently I am learning from W3schools.

Comment: @PrabhuM You can read a good tutorial [here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/descendantselector)

Comment: please tell me the concept name.

Comment: @PrabhuM Concept? You mean the selector name, did you saw the tutorial? It's called `Descendant Selector`